# retrieve folders names only from a zip file with php?

Tags: php, zip

I'm trying to retrieve folders name from a zip file.
I wrote this simple function :

```
<?php
class zipadmin{
    private $filename ;
    private $folder ;
    public function __construct($filename,$folder){
        $this->zip = new ZipArchive;
        $this->file = $filename ;
        $this->folder = $folder ;
    }
    public function listzip(){
    if ($this->zip->open($this->file) == TRUE) {
        $info = $this->zip->statIndex(0);
        $output = str_replace('/','',$info['name']);
        return $output;
        }
    }
}
```

Problem that if the zip folder contain other files which is not included inside the folders it return all the files names.
I need it to return folders names only and discard any files name.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try to check when `$info['crc']` equals to zero.

```
class zipadmin{

  private $file;
  private $folder;
  private $zip;

  public function __construct($filename, $folder) {
    $this->zip = new ZipArchive;
    $this->file = $filename ;
    $this->folder = $folder ;
    }

  public function listzip() {
    $res = false;
    if ($this->zip->open($this->folder . $this->file) == TRUE) {
      $i = 0;
      while ($info = $this->zip->statIndex($i)) {
        if ($info['crc'] == 0 && preg_match('#^[^/]*?/$#', $info['name']))
          $res[] = preg_replace('#^([^/]*?)/$#', '$1', $info['name']);
        $i++;
        }
      }
    return $res;
    }

}
```

**Usage example:**

```
$z = new zipadmin('test.zip', './'); // test.zip in my example is in same folder
print_r($z->listzip());
```

**Output** (array of root-directories only):

```
Array
(
    [0] => folder1
    [1] => folder2
    [2] => folder3
    [3] => folder4
)
```

In my `test.zip` archive I have few files in root directory of archive and 4 directories `folder1`, `folder2`, `folder3` and `folder4`with some files and sub-directories inside them. Running method against archive with no folders returns boolean **false**.

**Update:**

- Fixed regex pattern to match everything before first slash `/`.

Comment: Warning: ZipArchive::statIndex() [ziparchive.statindex]: Invalid or unitialized Zip object

Comment: Tell me what parameters you passed into `__construct` method? Be sure that your **$folder** parameter ends with slash, like `new zipadmin('myarchive.zip', 'folder/to/archive/');`. I've just tested it against few zip archives on different locations and it works fine.

Comment: In short, you mast provide correct path and filename as parameters of your class constructor.

Comment: im sure im passing the right param and when i changed it to the old one it works nice :)

Comment: zip filepath is defined with `$this->folder . $this->file` so that's place where to look for your issue. Nobody can guess what are you doing right there because you haven't provide any sample code here, like how you use this class, where is it located, where you're calling it from, where are your zip files. There are plenty of reasons why it doesn't work but for sure, it's wrong **PATH/TO/your.zip**.

Comment: I've just tested it on my both Windows & Linux servers and it works fine with my zip files.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9399/discussion-between-wh1t3h4ck5-and-marco)

Comment: This will not work correctly. statIndex() returns the value 0 (zero) for the checksum for empty files too. I searched for a long time and tested all documented methods, but there seems to be no way to check if an entry is a folder or file.