# Acces a file in a file upload input

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload, zip

I have a typical file upload element on a webpage:

```
<input type="file" id="zipFileUploader">
```

When a user selects a file, I want to do some preprocessing with the file, so I use this jQuery:

```
$("#zipfileUploader").change(function()
{
    var file = $(this).val();
});
```

But that only gives me the name of the file, not the actual content or bytes. How can this be achieved?

What I would like to do is determine the names of the files in the zip file (let's assume it has no directories) so I can populate a select with those values. After the user has selected the name of a file inside the zip, the entire form can be submitted and the server knows which filz inside the zip it has to look for.

Comment: for some security reason you can't access these files

Comment: Aha... and is there a way to send ONLY the file to the server, and not the entire form? I'm now using ajax to send the entire formdata to the server to do this processing of the zip for me, but this is more than necessary.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9905279

Comment: Or perhaps http://www.jqueryrain.com/2013/03/jszip-create-read-and-edit-zip-files-with-javascript/